# OPTIMIZE SQL QUERY WITH NO EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables, F_NSE, F_LTR, F_TRA, INVENTARIO.

Table INVENTARIO contain data for last stock for a product. F_NSE is table for product trazability (bacth date,..), F_LTR contains data for product selling and F_TRA contains data on the INVOICE. I need calculte the real STOCK for a product from the last date of INVENTARIO table.

One product can be row in INVETARIO table or not.

The problem is with NOT EXISTS clause in the query, is not optimize:

```
SELECT T0.NSENSE AS LOTE, REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, T0.FCONSE, 103), '01/01/1900', ''), '/20', '/') AS FCONSE,
SUM(T0.CANNSE) AS UNIDADES, T2.AORTRA AS CODALM,  T1.ARTLTR
FROM F_NSE AS T0 
INNER JOIN F_LTR AS T1 ON T0.DOCNSE = 'TR' AND T0.TIPNSE = ''
    AND T0.CODNSE = T1.DOCLTR AND T0.POSNSE = T1.LINLTR 
INNER JOIN F_TRA AS T2 ON T2.DOCTRA = T1.DOCLTR
LEFT OUTER JOIN Stock_Inventario_Pruebas AS T3 ON T3.CODART = T1.ARTLTR 
                    AND T3.CODALM = T2.AORTRA AND T3.NSENSE = T0.NSENSE 
WHERE (
  NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT INVENTARIO
    FROM dbo.ERP_Stock_Inventario_Pruebas AS T3
    WHERE (T1.ARTLTR = CODART))) AND
    T1.ARTLTR ='125554705' OR T2.FECTRA > T3.INVENTARIO 
    AND T1.ARTLTR = '125554705' 
    GROUP BY T0.NSENSE, T0.FCONSE, T1.ARTLTR,T2.AORTRA
    )
  )
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the syntax suggests SQL Server.

Comment: Not possible to optimize; you have to do a TABLE SCAN.  Each and every row in that table has to be checked.

Comment: Sure it can be optimized. You need to convert the NOT EXISTS to a pair of outer joins (for the OR condition), and then check for NULLS on the PKs (or some field) do make sure there are no matches for either..

Comment: Please can tell me how change the NOT EXISTS for 2 OUTER JOIN?

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote the query so I find it easier to read:

```
SELECT T0.NSENSE AS LOTE,
       REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), T0.FCONSE, 103), '01/01/1900', ''), '/20', '/') AS FCONSE, 
       SUM(T0.CANNSE) AS UNIDADES, 
       T2.AORTRA AS CODALM, T1.ARTLTR
FROM F_NSE T0 INNER JOIN
     F_LTR T1
     ON T0.DOCNSE = 'TR' AND T0.TIPNSE = '' AND
        T0.CODNSE = T1.DOCLTR AND T0.POSNSE = T1.LINLTR INNER JOIN
     F_TRA T2
     ON T2.DOCTRA = T1.DOCLTR LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Stock_Inventario_Pruebas T3
     ON T3.CODART = T1.ARTLTR AND T3.CODALM = T2.AORTRA AND T3.NSENSE = T0.NSENSE 
WHERE T1.ARTLTR ='125554705' AND
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM dbo.ERP_Stock_Inventario_Pruebas T3
                   WHERE T1.ARTLTR = T3.CODART
                  ) OR
       T2.FECTRA > T3.INVENTARIO 
      )
GROUP BY T0.NSENSE, T0.FCONSE, T1.ARTLTR,T2.AORTRA;
```

For this query, I would recommend indexes on `F_LTR(ARTLTR)` and `ERP_Stock_Inventario_Pruebas(CODART)`.

I do wonder why the left join uses more columns than the `NOT EXISTS`.  Logic more more typically look like this:

```
. . .
     Stock_Inventario_Pruebas T3
     ON T3.CODART = T1.ARTLTR AND T2.FECTRA > T3.INVENTARIO 
WHERE T1.ARTLTR ='125554705' 
. . .
```

This doesn't do exactly what your query does; it just makes more sense to me.

Comment: Sergio, I think you can use 3 instead of 103 like: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), T0.FCONSE, 3), '01/01/1900', '')` and remove replace. Removing a function helps, a lot. Try it out.

Comment: Hi, one product can have data in INVENTARIO table. Example: Product 125554705 have data in INVENTARIO table, then i have look the last inventory date for this product (T2.FECTRA > T3.INVENTARIO). But other product cann´t data in INVENTARIO TABLE. In this case LEFT OUTER JOIN shown NULL VALUE.  Last this AND T3.NSENSE = T0.NSENSE is because one product can have multiples serial number

Answer (score 0):

I think this is equivalent to your restatement of the SQL, but without the correlated subquery. Replace the (primary key) with a mandatory field name so you know if it's missing, the join is missing.

```
SELECT T0.NSENSE AS LOTE,
       REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),
       T0.FCONSE, 103), '01/01/1900', ''), '/20', '/') AS FCONSE, 
       SUM(T0.CANNSE) AS UNIDADES, 
       T2.AORTRA AS CODALM,
       T1.ARTLTR

FROM F_NSE T0 

INNER JOIN F_LTR T1
     ON T0.DOCNSE = 'TR' 
     AND T0.TIPNSE = '' 
     AND T0.CODNSE = T1.DOCLTR 
     AND T0.POSNSE = T1.LINLTR 

INNER JOIN F_TRA T2
     ON T2.DOCTRA = T1.DOCLTR 

LEFT OUTER JOIN Stock_Inventario_Pruebas T3
     ON T3.CODART = T1.ARTLTR 
     AND T3.CODALM = T2.AORTRA 
     AND T3.NSENSE = T0.NSENSE 

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ERP_Stock_Inventario_Pruebas T4
    ON T1.AR√LTR = T4.CODART

WHERE T4.(primary key) IS NULL
    OR T2.FECTRA > T3.INVENTARIO 

GROUP BY T0.NSENSE, T0.FCONSE, T1.ARTLTR,T2.AORTRA;
```

Comment: One problem with this query when i have tested more time. When TABLE ERP_STOCK_INVENTARIO_PRUEBAS have ONE RECORD. For example  product a have 2 rows, one per NSE...